# proFTPD unable to connect after update ECONNREFUSED

Tags: networking, debian, ftp, proftpd, debian-jessie

I am working on Debian 8 - ran a series of automated system updates and now I am unable to connect to my local server running proFTPD.

I have made no changes to the client attempting to connect to the server.

I was connecting to the server on port 21 with no issues. Since my update when I try to connect in my usual way I get the following error:

```
ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
```

From my research the error states my connection is being refused by a firewall or something of the like. However, I am not running any firewall, iptables is set to allow "all" - this is a local server.

I have checked the proFTPD error logs, and there are no errors logged.

I have ran proFTPD config check and status check, both return positive (it is running)

When I try to run

```
telnet localhost 21
```

the result is

```
connection refused
```

when I run

```
telnet localhost 22
```

I get a connection.

When I try to sftp into my server i get an authentication failed (probably because I haven't set up the keys)

I have checked the proFTPD config file and it is listening on port 21.

I have spent the day on this, seems like it would be easy to fix, however I'm having no luck.

Question:

How can I get back to using port 21 and just connect using normal ftp?

Thanks

UPDATE

Further testing

```
ps -ef | grep proftpd
```

results show proftpd accepting connections

however

```
lsof -i : 21
```

shows nothing listening... so it looks like proftpd isn't actually listening for some reason

when checking port 22 it simply shows ssh

I read that proftpd may be blocked from listening on port 21 if something else is running.

```
fuser -n tcp 21
```

shows no other process attached to that port.

```
service proftpd status
```

returns "active (running)"

any other thoughts?

Comment: Try `netstat -tulpn|grep 21` to see if there is actually a listener.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I ran that command, blank response. So I'm guessing it isn't listening. How would I get it back up and running?

Comment: If it's blank, it is not listening.  Did you check the proftpd logs?

Comment: @JuliePelletier   yes. there are no errors at all. just starting and stopping (when i restart the server)

Comment: Did you install it through `inetd` or `standalone`?

Comment: standalone - confirmed through the .conf file under servertype. Perhaps I should just reinstall under inetd???

Comment: `standalone` should be fine.  It doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: What does your full `proftpd.conf` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I must have installed something which enabled secure ftp, and this somehow disabled the un-encrypted connection on port 21

In the proFTPD.conf file, at the very end, there was a directive to enable modules in conf.d folder

in the conf.d folder, there is sftpd.conf, asking to run secure ftp on port 2222

before making any changes I run

```
lsof -i :2222
```

the result is proFTPD is listening for a connection on port 2222. When I check port 21, nothing is listening for a connection.

I commented out the include line in proFTPD.conf

```
include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/
```

Then I restart proFTPD and now I can connect normally again. I have no idea why enabling secure ftp would disable normal ftp.

Hope this helps someone else... the amount of time wasted on this problem is unreal.